# Preg_match word boundaries in php

Tags: php, regex

I’m trying this, to get word in word boundaries with unicode characters:

```
if(preg_match("/(?<!\p{L})jaunā(?!\p{L}) Iel.*/iu", "Jaunā. Iela") > 0){
    echo "<h1>Match!</h1>";

}
else{
    echo "<h1>dont match</h1>";
}
```

Why I’m getting „Don’t match”?

I want to find word “jaunā” in all variations for example: 
text ,jaunā text
text jaunā, text
text ,jaunā! text
 
jaunā text 
jaunā, text 
etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following regex:

```
/(?<!\p{L})jaunā(?!\p{L}).*? Iel.*/iu
```

After `jaunā` you have also `.` character, so with `.*?` you can match any other characters between `jaunā` and `Iela`

Answer (score 0):

You regex isn't matching a `dot` after `jaunā`:

Try this:

```
if(preg_match("/(?<!\p{L})jaunā(?!\p{L})\. Iel.*/iu", "Jaunā. Iela") > 0) {
    echo "<h1>Match!</h1>";
}
else{
    echo "<h1>dont match</h1>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to find word “jaunā” in all variations… for example:
text ,jaunā text 
text jaunā, text 
text ,jaunā! text 
etc.

Comment: Can you edit your question with some examples you want to match. (not easy to read from comments).